# Integral of $\frac{1}{1+x^{2/3}}$

Tags: integration

Can you explain how to integrate $ \frac{1}{1+x^{2/3}} $ for $ x \in [0,1]$ , we cannot use any formula directly to get the solution. Is there any simple approach to integrate such kind of functions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Start with the change of variables $u = x^{1/3}$

Answer (score 3):

Substitution works here: $$u =x^{1/3} \implies du = \frac 13 x^{-2/3}\,dx \implies dx = 3x^{2/3}\,du = 3u^2\,du$$

This gives us $$\int_0^1 \frac {3u^2}{1+u^2}\,du $$

Now do polynomial division to get $$\int_0^1 3\,du - 3\int \frac{du}{1+u^2}$$

Now, simply put $u = \tan \theta$ and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^{2/3}}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{3y^2\,dy}{1+y^2}=3-3\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dy}{1+y^2}=3\left(1-\frac{\pi}{4}\right).$$